# What is the command to delete a directory that has files in it?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I did `man rmdir`.  I also tried adding `-r` and `-f`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: did you put `sudo` before `rm`? depends on what you are trying to delete. If you do not have permissions for the current folder use `sudo`.

Comment: rm -rf dir-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rm -r directory
```

or

```
rm -rf directory
```

an explanation can easily be retrieved with `man rm`, here is an extract:

```
-r, -R, --recursive
          remove directories and their contents recursively
-f, --force
          ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

also from `man rmdir`:

```
rmdir

Remove directory, this command will only work if the folders are empty.
```